# Why do we consider time complexity as O(Logn) if the loop variables is divided / multiplied by a constant amount?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

Why do we consider time complexity as O(Logn) if the loop variables is divided / multiplied by a constant amount?
Like,

```
 for (int i = 1; i <=n; i *= c) {
       // some O(1) expressions
   }
   for (int i = n; i > 0; i /= c) {
       // some O(1) expressions
   }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well think like this - if the constant is positive integer then the complexity will be better than if it is `2`. So by considering the constant by `2` we won't suffer any lose in implying the complexity (Big-Oh) of the algorithm. Now if you consider `2` then it will run for approximately `log_2(n)` times. From that it comes into picture.

No matter what the constant be (positive integer) the complexity will be upper bounded by `O(log_2(n))` as a result we can consider the complexity to be Big_O bounded by `O(long_2(n))`. Accurate calculation would give `O(log_C(n))` for which `O(log_C(n)) < O(log_2(n))`. That's why this holds.

Comment: and for divide by 2?

Comment: @JawwadRafiq.: Yes it is dividing by `2`. So we get a monotonic decreasing sequence of `n`,`n/2`...`1`. which again gives logn and this can be used to approximate divide by `c` because for `c>1` `n,n/c,n/c^2..` goes to `1` faster than divide by `2`. So it is approixmated by `logn` correctly.

Comment: its mean, i can say, in both cases (* or /), its behaviors is, 100,50,25,12,6,3,1 , Or,  1,2,4,8,16,32,64 ... this seems problem is going to be half on every iteration, so its log(n) behavior?

Comment: In the first cases value of `i` is multiplied and in second it is divided...now all I am saying is doing the operation by C will be bounded by if we do the same by 2..that's it. The sequence for `i` in first case incrasing in second decreasing. Yes you get it right.